# What are the advantages of using the new ES2015 rest parameters in Javascript functions instead of using an array argument?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Some background first:
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/

> In the ES2015 a lot of new javascript features were introduced, and
> among them the rest parameters, enabling a function to accept an
> indefinite numbers of arguments  while avoiding some bad practices
> like using the arguments property of the functions.

In these examples we have two js functions that do the exact same thing:

*Accept an indefinite number of arguments.*

## NEW METHOD:

### (...args) => Rest parameter args treated as an array

```
function foo( ...bar){

  let ret = "";


  for(let i in args){

    ret += bar[i];
   
  }

  return ret;
}
```

This function can be invoked in these ways:

```
foo("a","b","c","d");   //returns => 'abcd'

let params = ["a","b","c","d"];

foo(...params);   //returns => 'abcd'
```

### OLD METHOD:

```
function foo(bar){

  var ret, i;
  
  ret = "";
  bar = bar || [];

  for(i in bar){

    ret += bar[i];
   
  }

  return ret;
}
```

This function can be invoked this way:

```
var args = ["a","b","c","d"];

foo(args);   //returns => 'abcd'
```

So it would appear that the only difference between the two methods lays just in the way you can invoke the function?

Is there some other advantage of using this new feature?

Comment: Can you find an advantage in using multiple parameters in general? Why wouldn't function just always have a single parameter only - where you can pass a list if you need more?

Comment: Where does that quote come from?  It's not on the linked page or the pdf linked from that page.  In fact, Googling it (or sections of it) comes up with nothing.  Without background all I see is Javascript that I've been using for a long time, where suitable

Comment: I'm asking just for an academic purpose, I use objects as argument for complex function too, However, since they added this new operators I just thought that maybe I was missing something.
I still can't see the reason for the downvote though.

Comment: I hope you mean "I am just curious" instead of "for academic purpose". Anyone can register on SO and write an answer without any reference or backup, so you must not blindly regard answerers as teachers.  Regardless of purpose, the question on the source of your quote remains valid, and it alone is not a bad reason for downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main use case of rest parameter is, as its name suggest, an indefinite number of "remaining" parameters.

Let's say we define a ES5 function, `defer`, that setTimeout a call to any function with any parameters:

```
function defer ( thisObject, callable ) {
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 2 );
   setTimeout( function(){
      callable.apply( thisObject, args );
   }, 0 );
}
defer( window, alert, 'Merry...' )
```

With rest parameters, we can completely get rid of `arguments`, without changing function signature:

```
function defer ( thisObject, callable, ... parameters ) {
   setTimeout( () => callable.apply( thisObject, parameters ), 0 );
}
defer( window, alert, "X'mas!" )
```

No calling code need to change, and our code is cleaner.
We keep the first two parameters, and automatically get the rest as an array.
This pattern is not that rare; [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is one such example.

The main point is to get rid of `arguments` without forcing callers to put everything in an array.
It is easy for you to make a function accepts only array, but the function may have hundreds of calls that all need to manually wrap parameters into an array for you - which may not even make sense.

1. Would you prefer `defer( window, alert, ["Foo"] )` or `defer( window, alert, "Bar" )`?
2. `defer( window, find, [] )` or `defer( window, find )`?
3. Wouldn't `Array.of( [ foo, bar, bas ] )` be a little confusing?
4. Like Bergi asked, why don't we put all parameters into a big one?

Hope this will clear things up.
Don't forget that features need not be as ground changing as arrow function or template string to be good.

Answer (score 0):

Rest parameters allow you to *spread* an iterable object and pass its parts to the function. Not all iterables are arrays; other [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterables) objects include Strings, Maps, and Sets.

When you write a function that accepts an array argument, you can only pass an array to it: `foo(arr)`. But if the caller doesn’t have an array, and only an iterable, they must “arrayify” it: `foo([...iterable])`, `foo(Array.from(iterable))`, etc.

When your function has rest parameters, the caller can spread any iterable, for example a string: `foo(...'hello') === foo('h','e','l','l','o')`. You could not do this if `foo` only accepted an array.

Now you might wonder, how much easier is it to call `foo(...iterable)` than `foo([...iterable])`? You’re right, it’s a little easier, but not by much. The rest parameter only offers a cleaner syntax, so technically we could refactor all our functions to not use them. However, it would make our code just a little bit more unreadable, as mentioned in other answers here.

```js
console.log( ['value: ', value] )

Math.min( [69, 42, 420] )

setTimeout(func, 300, [])
```